# Can I force some ports for listening only(mean servermdoe)

Tags: linux, ports, listen

In linux is there a way to tell the system that never give a port for client connection, but instead allocate it only for requests for listening(server).

That is, given a port P,
If a proc wants to connect to host X then dont give the port P, give some other port.
But if a proc wants to listen on port P then its OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` contains the only range of IPv4 ports that the system will use to connect with.

Comment: awesome...can i give a multiple ranges here.

Comment: i mean for e.g. 50000-55000 55100-60000. so that basically 55001 to 55099 are reserved for listening...Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It can only contain a single consecutive range.